# How do I extract whole numbers from a text file, put into a list, sort, get length and median in python?

Tags: python, sorting, text-files, median, alphanumeric

I have a desk top file (paragraphs of words, numbers and punctuation). I need to get just the numbers, sort them, print sorted list, length and median. I can open, read and extract just the numbers but all numbers (even my double digits) print on "\n". I am allowed to use import statistics.

I have tried several attempts. I know I need a .split(),.strip() and .append. I just cannot figure out where.

```
from statistics import median
def sorting_file(): 
    with open('C:\\Users\\wildk\\Desktop\\Numbers_in_text.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split().strip('n')
            for i in words:
                for number in i:
                     number = number.rstrip('n')
                    if(number.isnumeric()):
                         print(number)
def get_median():    
     for median in number:
        number = sorted
        median = sorted (number) [len(number)//2]
        print(median, len )                 

if __name__=='__main__':
     sorting_file()
     get_median()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFfwW.png)

Comment: You may need to share a few lines of your text file. That will inform how to resolve the issue you've having

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: On a side note, why are you doing `.strip('n')`? Does the letter "n" have some significance? Or did you mean `'\n'`?

Comment: p.s. You should copy/paste the output directly into your question as text rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_median` function has several problems:

- It references `number`, but that is an undefined name.
- During iteration you redefined `number` as `sorted`, which is a function. (Nothing gets sorted here)
- `sorted(number)` is then the same as `sorted(sorted)` which makes no sense.
- If that `sorted` call would work, you could not index it, as it is an iterator, not a list.
- `print(number, len)` would print two functions. I don't see how that is useful.
- Moreover, you have included a `median` function from `statistics` so you don't need `get_median` at all.

Then  `sorting_file` has problems too:

- It calls `.strip('n')` on a list. Lists don't have such a method, and it is a mystery why you would want something to happen with the letter `n` anyway
- `for number in i` is iterating the individual characters of a word (`i`). This is not useful. The word itself is what you are interested in.
- `.rstrip('n')` seems to serve no purpose
- The function only intends to *print* numbers, but doesn't actually convert them to numbers, nor collect them in some list to use for getting a median

Here is a correction that takes the above points into account:

```
from statistics import median

def sorting_file(): 
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            return [int(i) for i in line.split() if i.isnumeric()]

res = median(sorting_file())
print(res)
```